# More Efficent method to displaying list of countries in PHP than just in html?

Tags: php, html, loops, select

I have my current list of countries as displayed below, i would like to use a loop to display all these countries and just use less code to do it all so the page this is displayed on loads faster, is this possible?

Thanks

```
<select class="textbox-fixed-noimage" name="ADDRESS_COUNTRY">
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Afghanistan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Aland Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Albania' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Algeria' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'American' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Andorra' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Angola' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Angola">Angola</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Anguilla' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Antarctica' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Antigua and Barbuda' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Argentina' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Armenia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Aruba' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Australia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Austria' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Azerbaijan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bahamas' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bahrain' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bangladesh' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Barbados' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Belarus' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Belgium' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Belize' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Belize">Belize</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Benin' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Benin">Benin</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bermuda' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bhutan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bolivia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bosnia and Herzegovina' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Botswana' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bouvet Island' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Brazil' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'British Indian Ocean Territory' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Brunei Darussalam' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Bulgaria' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Burkina Faso' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Burundi' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cambodia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cameroon' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Canada' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cape Verde' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cayman Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Central African Republic' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Chad' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Chad">Chad</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Chile' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Chile">Chile</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'China' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="China">China</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Christmas Island' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Colombia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Comoros' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Congo' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Congo">Congo</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Congo, The Democratic Republic of The' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cook Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Costa Rica' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cote Divoire' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cote Divoire">Cote D'ivoire</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Croatia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cuba' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Cyprus' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Czech Republic' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Denmark' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Djibouti' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Dominica' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Dominican Republic' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Ecuador' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Egypt' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'El Salvador' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Equatorial Guinea' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Eritrea' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Estonia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Ethiopia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Faroe Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Fiji' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Finland' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Finland">Finland</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'France' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="France">France</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'French Guiana' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'French Polynesia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'French Southern Territories' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Gabon' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Gambia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Georgia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Germany' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Ghana' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Gibraltar' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Greece' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Greece">Greece</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Greenland' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Grenada' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Guadeloupe' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Guam' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Guam">Guam</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Guatemala' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Guernsey' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Guinea' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Guinea-bissau' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Guyana' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Haiti' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Holy See (Vatican City State)' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Honduras' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Hong Kong' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Hungary' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Iceland' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'India' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="India">India</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Indonesia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Iran' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Iran">Iran</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Iraq' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Ireland' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Isle of Man' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Israel' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Israel">Israel</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Italy' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Italy">Italy</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Jamaica' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Japan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Jersey' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Jersey">Jersey</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Jordan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Kazakhstan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Kenya' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Kiribati' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Korea, Democratic Peoples Republic of' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Korea, Democratic Peoples Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Korea, Republic of' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Kuwait' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Kyrgyzstan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Lao Peoples Democratic Republic' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Lao Peoples Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Latvia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Lebanon' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Lesotho' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Liberia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Liechtenstein' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Lithuania' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Luxembourg' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Macao' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Macao">Macao</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Madagascar' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Malawi' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Malaysia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Maldives' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Mali' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Mali">Mali</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Malta' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Malta">Malta</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Marshall Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Martinique' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Mauritania' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Mauritius' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Mayotte' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Mexico' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Micronesia, Federated States of' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Moldova, Republic of' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Monaco ' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Mongolia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Montenegro' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Montserrat' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Morocco' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Mozambique' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Myanmar' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Namibia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Nauru' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Nepal' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Netherlands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Netherlands Antilles' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'New Caledonia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'New Zealand' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Nicaragua' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Niger' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Niger">Niger</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Nigeria' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Niue' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Niue">Niue</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Norfolk Island' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Northern Mariana Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Norway' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Norway">Norway</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Oman' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Oman">Oman</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Pakistan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Palau' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Palau">Palau</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Panama' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Panama">Panama</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Papua New Guinea' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Paraguay' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Peru' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Peru">Peru</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Philippines' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Pitcairn' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Poland' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Poland">Poland</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Portugal' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Puerto Rico' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Qatar' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Reunion' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Romania' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Romania">Romania</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Russian Federation' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Rwanda' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Saint Helena' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Saint Kitts and Nevis' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Saint Lucia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Saint Vincent and The Grenadines' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Samoa' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'San Marino' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Sao Tome and Principe' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Saudi Arabia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Senegal' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Serbia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Seychelles' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Sierra Leone' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Singapore' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Slovakia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Slovenia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Solomon Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Somalia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'South Africa' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Spain' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Spain">Spain</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Sri Lanka' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Sudan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Suriname' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Swaziland' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Sweden' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Switzerland' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Syrian Arab Republic' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Taiwan, Province of China' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Tajikistan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Tanzania, United Republic of' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Thailand' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Timor-leste' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Togo' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Togo">Togo</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Tokelau' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Tonga' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Trinidad and Tobago' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Tunisia' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Turkey' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Turkmenistan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Turks and Caicos Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Tuvalu' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Uganda' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Ukraine' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'United Arab Emirates' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'United Kingdom' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'United States' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="United States">United States</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'United States Minor Outlying Islands' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Uruguay' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Uzbekistan' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Vanuatu' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Venezuela' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Viet Nam' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Virgin Islands, British' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
    <option<?=$ADDRESS_COUNTRY == 'Virgin Islands, U.S.' ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ;?> value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Sure you make country table in your database, and foreach/while loop. If you need the code let me know, it is very easy. code to connect database, and code to foreach/while loop. that is it.

Comment: you can do this inserting these data in a DB and then rum a query which you can call a foreach.

Comment: You need to create an array with all the countries `$array = array('Afghanistan','Aland Islands',...);` and the use a loop with an `if` inside to select the selected

Comment: i was thinking of keeping it in the .php code to avoid calling the database each time, which would you suggest is the best to do this? store the data in the db or in the code itself ?

Comment: LOL ;) array is also a choice as SERPRO and Steven answer

Comment: Does your environment support short-tags? try to change `<?` to `<?php` Maybe that will fix the 'white screen'

Comment: Fixed my answer to add the `$` on `$ADDRESS_COUNTRY`.  Shouldn't throw an error anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array to store your list of countries.  You store this list in an external file and `include` it wherever you need it.

You can also store this list of countries in a table in your database, if you have one.

```
$countries = array(
    "Afghanistan",
    "Aland Islands",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "American Samoa",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Anguilla",
    "Antarctica",
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Argentina",
    "Armenia",
    "Aruba",
    "Australia",
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Bahamas",
    "Bahrain",
    "Bangladesh",
    "Barbados",
    "Belarus",
    "Belgium",
    "Belize",
    "Benin",
    "Bermuda",
    "Bhutan",
    "Bolivia",
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    "Botswana",
    "Bouvet Island",
    "Brazil",
    "British Indian Ocean Territory",
    "Brunei Darussalam",
    "Bulgaria",
    "Burkina Faso",
    "Burundi",
    "Cambodia",
    "Cameroon",
    "Canada",
    "Cape Verde",
    "Cayman Islands",
    "Central African Republic",
    "Chad",
    "Chile",
    "China",
    "Christmas Island",
    "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
    "Colombia",
    "Comoros",
    "Congo",
    "Congo, The Democratic Republic of The",
    "Cook Islands",
    "Costa Rica",
    "Cote Divoire",
    "Croatia",
    "Cuba",
    "Cyprus",
    "Czech Republic",
    "Denmark",
    "Djibouti",
    "Dominica",
    "Dominican Republic",
    "Ecuador",
    "Egypt",
    "El Salvador",
    "Equatorial Guinea",
    "Eritrea",
    "Estonia",
    "Ethiopia",
    "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",
    "Faroe Islands",
    "Fiji",
    "Finland",
    "France",
    "French Guiana",
    "French Polynesia",
    "French Southern Territories",
    "Gabon",
    "Gambia",
    "Georgia",
    "Germany",
    "Ghana",
    "Gibraltar",
    "Greece",
    "Greenland",
    "Grenada",
    "Guadeloupe",
    "Guam",
    "Guatemala",
    "Guernsey",
    "Guinea",
    "Guinea-bissau",
    "Guyana",
    "Haiti",
    "Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands",
    "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
    "Honduras",
    "Hong Kong",
    "Hungary",
    "Iceland",
    "India",
    "Indonesia",
    "Iran",
    "Iraq",
    "Ireland",
    "Isle of Man",
    "Israel",
    "Italy",
    "Jamaica",
    "Japan",
    "Jersey",
    "Jordan",
    "Kazakhstan",
    "Kenya",
    "Kiribati",
    "Korea, Democratic Peoples Republic of",
    "Korea, Republic of",
    "Kuwait",
    "Kyrgyzstan",
    "Lao Peoples Democratic Republic",
    "Latvia",
    "Lebanon",
    "Lesotho",
    "Liberia",
    "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya",
    "Liechtenstein",
    "Lithuania",
    "Luxembourg",
    "Macao",
    "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of",
    "Madagascar",
    "Malawi",
    "Malaysia",
    "Maldives",
    "Mali",
    "Malta",
    "Marshall Islands",
    "Martinique",
    "Mauritania",
    "Mauritius",
    "Mayotte",
    "Mexico",
    "Micronesia, Federated States of",
    "Moldova, Republic of",
    "Monaco",
    "Mongolia",
    "Montenegro",
    "Montserrat",
    "Morocco",
    "Mozambique",
    "Myanmar",
    "Namibia",
    "Nauru",
    "Nepal",
    "Netherlands",
    "Netherlands Antilles",
    "New Caledonia",
    "New Zealand",
    "Nicaragua",
    "Niger",
    "Nigeria",
    "Niue",
    "Norfolk Island",
    "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "Norway",
    "Oman",
    "Pakistan",
    "Palau",
    "Panama",
    "Papua New Guinea",
    "Paraguay",
    "Peru",
    "Philippines",
    "Pitcairn",
    "Poland",
    "Portugal",
    "Puerto Rico",
    "Qatar",
    "Reunion",
    "Romania",
    "Russian Federation",
    "Rwanda",
    "Saint Helena",
    "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
    "Saint Lucia",
    "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
    "Saint Vincent and The Grenadines",
    "Samoa",
    "San Marino",
    "Sao Tome and Principe",
    "Saudi Arabia",
    "Senegal",
    "Serbia",
    "Seychelles",
    "Sierra Leone",
    "Singapore",
    "Slovakia",
    "Slovenia",
    "Solomon Islands",
    "Somalia",
    "South Africa",
    "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands",
    "Spain",
    "Sri Lanka",
    "Sudan",
    "Suriname",
    "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
    "Swaziland",
    "Sweden",
    "Switzerland",
    "Syrian Arab Republic",
    "Taiwan, Province of China",
    "Tajikistan",
    "Tanzania, United Republic of",
    "Thailand",
    "Timor-leste",
    "Togo",
    "Tokelau",
    "Tonga",
    "Trinidad and Tobago",
    "Tunisia",
    "Turkey",
    "Turkmenistan",
    "Turks and Caicos Islands",
    "Tuvalu",
    "Uganda",
    "Ukraine",
    "United Arab Emirates",
    "United Kingdom",
    "United States",
    "United States Minor Outlying Islands",
    "Uruguay",
    "Uzbekistan",
    "Vanuatu",
    "Venezuela",
    "Viet Nam",
    "Virgin Islands, British",
    "Virgin Islands, U.S."
);
```

Then, with this array of countries, print them and check if each is selected using a for loop:

```
echo '<select class="textbox-fixed-noimage" name="ADDRESS_COUNTRY">';
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    $selected = $ADDRESS_COUNTRY == $country ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option {$selected} value=\"{$country}\">{$country}</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make array of countries and use `foreach` to extract through array. like,

```
 $countries = array("USA","UA","CHINA","JAPAN");
 echo "<select>";
 foreach($countries as $country)
  {
    echo "<option>".$country."</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
```